# pre tag not responsive in mobile

Tags: html, pre

my pre tag goes out of parent div in smaller screen. It's not responsive in mobile as u can see in the screenshot. Please help me to make it responsive

[image]

CSS:

```css
pre {
            background-color: #FFFFCC;
            border: 1px dashed #FF6666;
            padding-top: 7px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;
            padding-right: 10px;
            clear: both;
            }
```

Comment: Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Viewport Units** like **vw** or **vh** instead of **px** and **%** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

Try the attached code and if it doesn't work please let me know in the comments. I will try my best to solve your issue.

```css
pre {
     background-color: #FFFFCC;
     border: 1px dashed #FF6666;
     padding-top: 0.518vw;
     padding-bottom: 0.585vw;
     padding-left: 0.732vw;
     margin: 0.732vw;
     float: left;
     padding-right: 0.732vw;
     clear: both;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems to be not working as well :(

Comment: @DhirajBezbaruah I am really sorry that it didn't worked for you  but can you do me a favour  that as soon as you resolve this issue please let me know, I would love to know how you resolved it.

Comment: Hi I have added width: 100% along with your above code and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @DhirajBezbaruah I am so happy to hear that my answer helped you a bit and can you do me a favour by accepting and upvoting my answer, it would mean a lot to me. And thanks for saying me how you solved the issue completely.

Comment: @DhirajBezbaruah I am so happy that I solved your issue and thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer, you have made my day. I hope to get more chances to help you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the **pre** element is meant to **pre**serve text formating. That means that text will not be wrapped inside it, that's why it can expand the whole container.

Try setting the style rule `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: hidden;` whichever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pixels use percentage.

```css
pre {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    border: 1% dashed #FF6666;
    padding-top: 1.2%;
    padding-bottom: 1.2%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin: 1.5%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

That should make it so it re-size itself.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but that's not working for me :(